# How to enable Torch in Barcode scanner API in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, api, barcode

Using the [Barcode Scanner API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-lightning-barcodescanner.html) in Salesforce, is there a way to enable Torch for scanning during night time?

There doesn't seem to be an option for it in [BarcodeScannerOptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-lightning-barcodescanner-data-types.html).

I tried using an iframe to start video recording and enable the torch, but when starting the Barcode Scanner API, it seems to turn it off again automatically, before scanning.

**A code sample of the API**

```
const scanningOptions = {
    barcodeTypes: [ scanner.barcodeTypes.EAN_13 ],
    instructionText: 'Scan barcode',
    successText: 'Scanning complete.'
}; 

const result = await scanner.beginCapture( scanningOptions );
```

Comment: Are you on Android? I've not tested the barcode scanner recently. But on Android you can't turn on the torch during videos, because the video app itself might want to use the light as "flash" (not the best word in this context). There's no way to enable "flash" during LWC initiated scanning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work around this issue, I migrated to load QuaggaJS from inside an iframe.

https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/